# Is there a way to use a conditional kernel in openCV that only changes pixels on an image if the condition is true?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, blur, gaussianblur

I want to use a kernel that performs a pixel operation based on a *conditional expression*.

Let's say I have this grayscale image (6x6 resolution):

[image]

and I use a 3x3 pixel kernel, how would I change the value of the centre kernel pixel (centre) ***IF AND ONLY IF*** the centre pixel is the local minimum or maximum within the 3x3 kernel?

For example, say I wanted to set the centre kernel pixel to the ***average*** value of the surrounding 8 pixels, like this:

[image: , then set it to the average value of all surrounding 8 pixels.]

Is there a way to do this with `OpenCV`?

**EDIT: another more detailed example GIF - 9 passes implementing my example:**

[image]

This was produced in Excel using the following formula (not the relative cell references - they show the kernel shape of 3x3 around the focus 'picell':

```
=IF(OR(C55=MIN(B54:D56),C55=MAX(B54:D56)),(SUM(B54:D56)-C55)/8,C55)
```

Here is the top left corner of the table with the source values for the first pass (these values control the cell colour):

[image]

This table refers to another source table. Each frame in the GIF is the next calculated colour table. There are 3 tables of formulae in between each image frame. Here is more context:

[image]

Comment: Create a mask using your condition.  Then apply the morphology everywhere. Then use the mask to blend between the original and morphology processed image using np.where(mask=mask, processed, original)

Comment: Thanks. I know *what* I want to do, but I don't know ***how*** to do it. How do I 'create a mask'?

Comment: what code do you have so far? what data do you have? what can you provide? [ask], [mre]

Comment: I am pondering the logic of my example...it is possible that given enough iterations of applying a conditional mean it may end up effectively blurring the image beyond use, or even erasing it.

Comment: Post a real image and the exact condition you want to use.

Comment: @fmw42 added a more detailed example using conditional mean filter with 9 passes...but you can see why I am having second thoughts about that specific idea.

Comment: Most smoothing filters, if you iterate them often enough, will end up flattening the whole image. The opening and the closing are the only idempotent smoothing filters I can think of right now. So, yes, of course, you want to limit how many times you apply the filter.

Comment: You could edit your post to show what logic you used to produce the example GIFs.  At least then there would be a more substantial basis for discussion.

Comment: What was the exact mathematical conditional mean filter that was used. Please show an **original** image at normal resolution, not one that was expanded to show blocks for pixels and without grid or tick marks.

Comment: so you're looking for "local extrema". that's a min/max operation, or an "erode/dilate" morphology operation. you would calculate the local extremum for every pixel, i.e. apply the morphology operation. then you know for every pixel what the local extremal value is. then you can compare that value to the value of the pixel itself. if they're equal, that pixel *is* the local extremum. -- your excel skills are impressive but we all would appreciate a simple picture where a pixel is a pixel, no enlarging or annotations. that'd be the input to experiment on. I guess I could synthesize one myself

Comment: The pixels above were randomly generated in LibreOffice Calc (or Excel). I am trying to work out how to get a pixel array from a real image into Calc/Excel to run it through the same process.

Comment: I wish I'd known the true extent of your task. you hadn't hinted at gradients being a part of this. is this now the full extent of your task or is there going to be yet more to it? where does this data come from? is this perhaps a "CAPTCHA"?

Comment: Forgive me...I have spent 3 weeks reading all sorts of stuff about openCV and how to process images and I have a large data set with a wide variety of issues to deal with...I have never done any automated image processing up until this current task, and I am learning all new stuff. I accept that the goal I am trying to achieve is actually a formidable one. It is very, very difficult coming up with a set of processing rules that will be true for all input images with all the variations and inconsistencies...trying to normalize, denoise, and shift intensity in the right direction in very hard.

Comment: No CAPTCHA data (much as I hate those - we are being used to feed the AI beast...opinion only ;) ). It really is as banal as my scanned documents (mainly receipts). I have 10 years worth. It has always been a problem. I have a half implemented system...

Comment: I spent a good amount of money on OmniPage Ultimate years ago...it has never been able to give good enough results consistently. Perhaps it is because it needs a lot more training than I have given it. Not sure. Then I discovered Tesseract, but it gave worse results. Then I discovered videos on image preprocessing to improve OCR results, so I ended up on openCV, and that's what brought me here. I thought maybe if I could split my images by line, then use each line image to improve tesseract or OmniPage training perhaps they would start to work like they promised.

Comment: I even looking into fuzzy matching algorithms years ago to try and overcome the poor and inaccurate OCR text output....

Comment: "receipts" is another crucial piece of info. -- you'd do best to discard any thoughts of preprocessing. no rules can capture this complexity. -- get an OCR package that can handle the data. legacy OCR did threshold the page, then identify connected components (perhaps with some "clumping" to get the dot on an "i"...), then classified each connected component. that is *way way behind* state of the art. these days, the page is supposed to be treated with a CNN. it takes full grayscale info into account and it will deal with noise of various scales (including large-scale lighting variations).

Comment: ... and that CNN is for OCR, not for preprocessing. there is no preprocesing. the CNN is supposed to directly or indirectly infer characters or even entire words. -- the advantage of AI is that you can just train it on your specific data. the model figures it out. you don't have to.

Comment: ...I was afraid you might say something like that...so as mentioned above, I did think of maybe creating training data from a subset of my images by splitting then into lines (using a crude but seemingly effective way to identify a 'line' by creating a pixel sum per row and getting the mean), and then splitting each line into characters, using the same technique.

Comment: This question is a moving target. Please don't do that. You asked a question, and got a good answer from @ChristophRackwitz, exactly answering that question. What you should do then is accept the answer (and upvote), and ask a *new* question for your moved target.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - agreed, not totally a fair question. Yesterday I found docTR (github), and my preliminary testing reveals this to be possibly lightyears ahead of the stupid OmniPage Ultimate which caused an Ultimate pain because it couldn't recognise text well enough to be useful and which was Ultimately useless...(sigh), oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> [...] how would I change the value of the centre kernel pixel (centre) IF AND ONLY IF the centre pixel is the local minimum or maximum within the 3x3 kernel?
> For example, say I wanted to set the centre kernel pixel to the average value of the surrounding 8 pixels [...]

I'll demonstrate a few things first. I'll work with small arrays, 16 by 16. I'll show them enlarged so you can stare at the pixels conveniently. When I talk about these images, I mean the 16x16 data, not the visualizations in this post.

Let's start with random noise because that is what you first presented.

```
noise = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(16, 16), dtype=np.uint8)
```

[image: noise]

Now you need to know about morphology operations. Erosion and dilation are calculating the local minimum/maximum value.

```
local_max_values = cv.dilate(noise_img, None, iterations=1)
local_min_values = cv.erode(noise_img, None, iterations=1)
```

[image: local_max_values]
[image: local_min_values]

What's that good for? You can *compare* pixel values. If a pixel is equal to the local extremum, it must be *a* local extremum. It's not unique because let's say two adjacent pixels have the same low/high value. They're both extrema.

Let's compare:

```
is_min = (noise_img == local_min_values)
is_max = (noise_img == local_max_values)
is_extremum = is_min | is_max
```

[image: is_min]
[image: is_max]
[image: is_extremum]

Those are masks. They're binary, boolean. You can use them either for *indexing*, or for multiplication. You can imagine what happens when you multiply elementwise by 0 or 1, or do that with an inverted mask.

I'll demonstrate indexing but first I'll need the local averages.

```
averaged = cv.blur(noise_img, (3, 3))
```

[image: averaged]

Now I can make a copy of the input (or I could work on it directly) and then overwrite all the extremal pixels with the average values at those positions.

```
denoised = noise_img.copy()
denoised[is_extremum] = averaged[is_extremum]
```

[image: denoised]

Yes, this calculates the average for all pixels, even if you don't need it. Practically, you wouldn't save any time by calculating only some of the averages.

If you switch back and forth between this and the source image, you'll see local extrema being erased. Other pixels that used to be "second place" have now become extrema. Another round of this will progressively smooth the entire picture until everything is quite flat.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate approach using Python/OpenCV.

Convert your mathematical condition into mathematical OpenCV methods to produce a mask (binary or otherwise). Then use the mask to blend between the input and the 3x3 averaged input.

Here my condition will be a binary image that is white where the difference between the averaged image and the input is larger than some threshold value and elsewhere the mask is black.

Input (random image created by script and enlarged for viewing):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# create noise input
np.random.seed(1)
noise = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(16, 16), dtype=np.uint8)

# create 3x3 average
average = cv2.blur(noise, (3, 3))

# create condition "mask" where difference between average and noise is greater than some percent threshold
threshVal = 40   #percent
threshVal = 255*threshVal/100
mask = cv2.subtract(average, noise)
mask = cv2.threshold(mask, threshVal, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# process image based upon condition 
result = np.where(mask, average, noise)

# compute percent change
change = cv2.absdiff(result, noise)
pct_change = 100*cv2.divide(change, noise)
print(np.average(pct_change))

# save 10x expanded results
cv2.imwrite('noise.png', cv2.resize(noise, (0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', cv2.resize(mask, (0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
cv2.imwrite('noise_conditional_average.png', cv2.resize(result,(0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))

# show 10x expanded results
cv2.imshow('noise', cv2.resize(noise, (0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
cv2.imshow('mask', cv2.resize(mask, (0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
cv2.imshow('result', cv2.resize(result,(0,0), fx=10, fy=10, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Mask Image (enlarged for viewing):

[image]

Result Image (enlarged for viewing):

[image]

```
Change Percent:  9.671875
```

Alternating Input and Result to Show Changes:

[image]

Comment: This is also a great answer - I want to marked both these are the answer, but I must choose one. And I accept @CrisLuengo's comment. It was not really a fair question as it changed as I added more info. But thank you!

Comment: No problem. Don't worry about it. I was answering your original question about conditions on the average. I had not noticed you changes to the center pixel min or max.